# How to add background image to SharePoint onlinemidern site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Modern SharePoint Online site. I'm having problems working out on how to add a corporate image as the background image to the landing page.

Any advise on easiest way to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings, then to "change the look", choose a template (any, it doesnt really matter), and theres an option to change the background image on the top left.

If a .png or .gif - it needs to be smaller than 150kb.

Also, you can change the master page logo (the logo that appears in the top left of your site, next to the menu) by going to settings, then "Title, Description, Logo".

Answer (score 0):

To add a background image to a modern page, we need to use SPFx extension to insert CSS to achieve it in modern page.

You can refer to the [react-application-injectcss](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss) to inject CSS or [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) with CSS.